# How do I solve this binomial distribution problem?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find the probability of having 2,3 or 4 successes in five trials of a binomial experiment in which the probability of success is 40%.

Comment: "How do I solve" The usual way: Apply formula, calculate result. It's not fun, or particularily interesting or challenging, but such is life some times.

Comment: Find the probability for 2 trials only. The "or" means do it for 3 and 4 then add all the results together (2, 3 and 4 successes are mutually exclusive events).

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{P}(2\le X\le 4)=\sum_{k=2}^{4}{5\choose k}(0,4)^k(1-0,4)^{5-k}$$

Comment: What's the answer rounded to the nearest tenth of a percent?